# In Matrix-chain multiplication, access to 2D arrays(parameter) error

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing, matrix-multiplication, chain

I have difficulties in accessing 2D array. I pass the `int** s`(s is 2D dimension) as parameter. And I tried to reuse the element of it with index below form(`s[sp][jc]`, I also tried `*(*(s+sp)+jc))`, and this makes error(there's no error code but only shut down program). What is the problem? Or if I can't use 2D array as parameter, than how can I print the sequence of parenteses and matrix of matrix-chain multiplication --> like this: `((a(bc))((de)f))`.

```
void printParenthesis(int sp, int ep, int jc, int** s) {
   printf("Debug\n");

   if(sp==ep) {
      printf("( %d ", sp);
      return;
   }
   else {
      printParenthesis(sp, jc, s[sp][jc], s);
      printParenthesis(jc+1, ep, s[jc+1][ep], s);
      printf(") ");
   }
}
int main() {
    ...
    int s[matNum-1][matNum]
    ...
    printParenthesis(0, matNum, jc, (int**)s);
```

Comment: `int **` is not `int[][]`

Answer (score 0):

C does not deal actually with 2D-arrays the way you expect it. It does it the C-way.

Let's observe `*(*(s+sp)+jc))` first. `(s+sq)` is of type `int*`, **not** `int**`. That said, you immediately know what causes the crash. The expression dereferences an `int*` twice, which is not realistic to work properly.

To correct your code, you have to change definition of the array's parameter to

```
void printParenthesis(int sp, int ep, int jc, int (*s)[SIZE_S])
```

such that your 2D-array has fixed size length.

In other words you are passing an array of `SIZE_S` pointers to `int`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there any other approach if the case is 2D-array size is variable? If not, is it better transform that function to iterative form in main function?